# A more feature filled mintmenu like applet for Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: xubuntu, applet, mint, mate

I do not want to install the mintmenu. I am requesting anything that is XFCE NATIVE.

I'd love to see something like Mintmenu written for XFCE.

I can't install MintMenu because the Mate desktop does not exist for PowerPC yet.

Running Xubuntu 12.04

Anyone know of any XFCE applets in development that work similarly to the MintMenu?

TIA

Comment: If you downvote please explain why. The OP is not asking for help with Linux Mint but with xubuntu, a supported Ubuntu flavor.

Comment: With that said, some people have managed to get [elementary's slingshot](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2011/12/install-and-configure-slingshot.html) to run on XFCE, but this info is a year old and might be outdated by now. edit: here's another, [more recent guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2117202)

Comment: Wow! @MHC thank you so much. I didn't expect anyone would answer. I will try out your suggestions and post my results.

Comment: Ok so i installed slingshot, and it's almost the perfect solution except for some reason it runs on the top left hand side of the screen .... looks buggy too. http://askubuntu.com/questions/281211/make-slingshot-launcher-run-in-fullscreen-mode-on-xubuntu

Comment: Good to hear that you've found my comment helpful. I had seen your question earlier this morning and upvoted it. I hope you'll be able to get the launcher to work correctly.

Comment: I so much wish I knew how to write a xfce applet. I'd just throw xfce4-appfinder in there and get it to appear from a launcher like menu style. It has everything except for a favorites category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another really awesome way to do this.
There are the other options above such as
1) trying to get mint menu installed by PPA (or compiling for my powerpc)
2) by PPA or (compiling for my powerpc) the elementaryOS slingshot launcher
3)

install dockbarX from webupd8 ppa (i had to compile it from their source )

DockbarX is an amazing dock applet for xfce panel. It combines the launchers and taskbar into one so that clicking on an icon will not create a new icon on the panel.

This allows you to create a launcher for the `xfce4-appfinder` and create an icon for it like I did with the `ubuntu-logo` icon

Then you can run the app and just keep it open the whole time. It will work just as if it were a menu icon but FASTER!

[image]

As  of 2013 spring, this question has been solved  by whisker menu.

Here are some PPAs

Install Whisker Menu in Xubuntu

To add the official PPA and install Whisker Menu in (X)Ubuntu 13.10, 13.04, 12.10 or 12.04 (with Xfce 4.8), use the commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gottcode/gcppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin
```

Important: if you're using (X)Ubuntu 12.04 and you've upgraded to Xfce 4.10, use the following PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:landronimirc/xfce
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin
```

Once installed, right click the panel and select Panel > Add New Items, then select "Whisker Menu" and click "Add".

Answer (score 1):

Can't help you on a native xfce menu, but MATE is available on PowerPC.  See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1918246&page=29&p=12573621#post12573621 .  I've had the Mint Menu working in Xubuntu on PowerPC, but its annoying scrolling drives me nuts!  You have to upgrade to xfce 4.10 for it to work.

I've compiled most of MATE 1.6, just python-caja that is currently defeating me http://forums.mate-desktop.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=1660 .

Comment: ahh! Thank you for the link. I know most of the instructions online say to upgrade to xfce 4.10 but I am so afraid to break my system again. I hate having to fix this thing and get the drivers all working over and over again. trying to play it safe this time. The next time I will upgrade is the next LTS release. But I wish someone would backport xfce 4.10 to 12.04 because really the LTS support is meaningless if you don't get up to date packages, what is being supported?? anyways. rant over.