# make slingshot-launcher run in fullscreen mode on Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, elementary

Here's what I got cooking on Xubuntu 12.04

SLINGSHOT LAUNCHER for precise

[elementary-daily ppa](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/daily/+packages?field.name_filter=slingshot-launcher&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=#)

but it runs in a mini mode on the upper left of the screen. Installing gala or mutter did not get it running full screen?

[image]

being able to run it fullscreen like in previous versions or being able to change the position of the window and arrow would be an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design - from the Elementary OS [blog](http://elementaryos.org/journal/luna-beta-1-released)

> Slingshot is our new app launcher. It displays an optimal 3x5 paged grid of app icons, the result of iterative design and user testing. We’ve targeted three classes of users: those used to the point-and-click/tap mechanism present in modern interfaces, those accustomed to the category-based list view, and those who want full keyboard control including opening, searching, and launching in just a couple of keystrokes. Slingshot is built for speed and utilizes Granite which ensures consistency with the rest of the system.

I did notice that you can edit the size of the grid, using dconf-editor. Navigate to org.pantheon.desktop.slingshot and change the number of rows and columns to whatever suits you. Still no full-screen mode though.

Comment: I guess it has changed. It used to run full screen. I wonder if there are some options somewhere to get it to run full screen again.

Comment: @JoshuaRobison No they did remove the source for the previous full screen version of it and it's only available as "Launchpad" in the Ubuntu-based Pear Linux.